# gallery in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm having problems with implementing a gallery. It always shows me this error:

undefined method `geometry' for #

I read it and I know what it means...but I'm doing the iteration right:

```
<% @gallery_photos.each do |g| %>
```

anyway, here is the code of the gallery_detail and the method gallery_detail...

https://gist.github.com/899049

also, I'm trying to follow this model of rotator, but I think that I'm not doing it in the right way, since it has an href element on the thumb image that has to match with the img src...anyway, here is the model that I'm trying to follow:

http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/

Update: I solved the problem with the image, but I still don't know how to implement the jquery part of the page. The href of the image thumb has to match with the image source of the image in the main_page div.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this?

```
 def gallery_detail

   @gallery_photos = GalleryPhoto.all

 end
```

and in the html:

```
<div class="main_page">
   <% if @gallery_photos.first.geometry == 'vertical' %>
      <img src="<%= gallery_photos.first.photo.url("large") %>" style="height:420px;" />
   <% else %>
      <img src="<%= gallery_photos.first.photo.url("large") %>" style="width:500px;" />
   <% end %>
   <div class="desc">
      <a href="#" class="collapse">Close Me!</a>
        <div class="block">
           <h2>Title</h2>
           <small>Date</small>
           <p>Copy</p>
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<div class="image_thumb">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <% @gallery_photos.each do |g| %>
        <% if g.geometry == 'vertical' %>
          <a href="#">  <img src="<%= g.photo.url("small") %>" style="height:65px;"/></a>
        <% else %>
          <img src="<%= g.photo.url("small") %>" style="height:65px; width:80px;"/></li></a>
        <% end %> 
      <% end %>
      <div class="block">
         <h2>Title</h2>
         <small>Date</small>
         <p>Copy</p>
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: apneia, I can't do it cause the intention it's to show to just one photo in the main-page div, but in the thumb div list all the photos.

Comment: thanks apneia, but I'm still in trouble with the rotator, how do I implement this? I have to have an href in the thumb image matching with the image src of the main-page image.

Comment: can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it failing on line 12

```
<% if @gallery_photos.geometry == 'vertical' %>
```

and not on line 33? I don't think it has to do with you iterating over the collection. Line 12 looks like you are trying to call it directly on the collection of `GalleryPhoto`s.